# Printing to physical printer via a PDF printer

Tags: pdf, printer, redirection

I am looking for a solution to print to a physical printer via a PDF printer (eg. Bullzip).
I would need this because Bullzip has the possibility to use a predefined pdf document as the background of the printout (company data, etc), which out of various reasons cannot be used in the template.

Is there a solution for that (I couldn't find one at the moment) to print to Bullzip (or similar), but the result would come out of an actual printer?

Comment: Why not just set bullzip to open the created pdf doc automatically - when open all you are missing is a click on print?

Comment: yes, that can be done when I am doing the process, but I would like to avoid it as much as possible when my clients are doing the invoicing, so that they wouldn't need to press print from the program, and then print from Adobe Reader again, setting another printer manually.

Comment: Ah! You're trying to code the functionality into your application? In that case have a look at the bullzip api - there has got to be a way of rendering the pdf's in the background.

Comment: Well, coding it into the app would be a bit strong statement, since I am only distributing, implementing and supporting it, but I'm sure the Bullzip API will have some useful info we cann use. Coding it into the implementation would be more precise. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It seems that there is a possibility with PDFCreator to do whatever you want with the pdf after you save it. It can forward it as well, so case could be closed. It requires a bit of VB, but it's not criminal.